# In Django, how do I add a join table relation to an existing model?

Tags: python-3.x, django, join, django-models, migration

I'm using Python 3.9 and Django 3.2.  I have these models.  The second is a join table for the first

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType, blank=False)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address, through='CoopAddressTags')
 

class CoopAddressTags(models.Model):
    # Retain referencing coop & address, but set "is_public" relation to NULL
    coop = models.ForeignKey(Coop, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
```

I would like to actually reference the join table in my first model, so I added

```
address_tags = models.ManyToManyField('CoopAddressTags')
```

like so

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType, blank=False)
    address_tags = models.ManyToManyField('CoopAddressTags')
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address, through='CoopAddressTags')
```

but I'm getting this error when I run a script to generate migraitons

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations directory
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
directory.Coop.address_tags: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'directory.Coop.address_tags' clashes with field name 'directory.CoopAddressTags.coop'.
    HINT: Rename field 'directory.CoopAddressTags.coop', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'directory.Coop.address_tags'.
```

I'm not clear what this means or how to resolve it.  The goal is that when I have a "Coop" object, I can reference its addresses and whether or not those addresses are public.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with what you're trying to achieve, but `coop.addresses` does a join to `CoopAddressTags`. Since your second M2M also does the same it says there are conflicting reverse names

Comment: The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) explain nicely how the M2M with intermediate table must be used.

Comment: It does not seem to make much sense to have two `ManyToManyField`s. You `CoopAddressTags` seems to act like a through model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the `address_tags` to the `CoopAddressTags` which means that now the default value for the [**`related_query_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) of the `ManyToManyField` that targets the `Address` model has `'coop'` as value, and this is the same name as the `coop` relation in the `CoopAddressTags`.

But the modeling is very odd. Very likely you only want to define a single `ManyToManyField` between `Coop` and `Address`, with the `CoopAddressTags` as [*junction table* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). You thus model this as in your initial attempt.

If you need the items from the `through=…` model, you access this with:

```
my_coop.coopaddresstags_set.all()
```

or you can filter with:

```
Coop.objects.filter(coopaddresstags__is_public=True, adresses=my_address)
```

This will then for example retrieve all `Coop`s for which there is a public relation between *`my_address`* and that `Coop`.